# Php, mysql, session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a problems with receiving data from forms on the website. i mean, after successfuly registration user have to see string like this: Hello "name", but instead of this i receive all strings, but every string have to be special for every new user. How can i do this with session? Help. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't provided us with enough information here to answer the question. What is in the files? What does "work well" mean?

Comment: have you tried, or at least thought of, typing your *exact* question title into google or any other search engine?

Comment: <?php
     include_once("db.php"); if(isset($_POST['add'])) {
 $username = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['username'])));
 $email = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags(trim($_POST['email'])));
 $password = md5($_POST['password']);
 mysql_query(" 
                      INSERT INTO users(username,email,password) 
                      VALUE ('$username','$email','$password')
                     ");header('Location: http://main.php/');
         exit;
         
         mysql_close(); 
     }   
    ?>

Comment: So, where i need to write header(''Location main.php"); exit();?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes, i have, but i can`t find anything. Can you help me in this question?

Comment: @user9085541 literally the _first_ result on google is a stackoverflow-question with the _same_ content, which has been answered. also: **don't** use deprecated `mysql`-functions but PDO/MySQLi instead, and **don't** use md5 to hash passwords, use `password_hash()` instead, and use parameterised queries.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann okey, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a good method to perform a redirection that works in all situations:

```
// $url contains the page to which you want to redirect the user

function redirect($url)
{
    if (!headers_sent())
        header('Location: '.$url);
    else
    {  
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
        echo 'window.location.href="'.$url.'";';
        echo '</script>';
        echo '<noscript>';
        echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='.$url.'"/>';
        echo '</noscript>';
    }

    exit();
}
```

Use it once the user registration is completed:

```
redirect('successfull_registration.php');
```

Answer (score -1):

The `header` function is used to redirect.

```
<?php header('Location: thispage.php'); ?>
```

Include this line in the page from which you want to redirect to `thispage.php`.

Or in case If you have the URL in some variable so write like this

```
<?php header('Location: '.$URL); ?>
```

---

## Warning!!

Do not add unnecessary `NewLine` on the top of the page, or the `header` function will not work and return [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) have already been sent.

Comment: If you're going to add a warning to your answer at least have the specific reason on-hand rather than "sometimes it doesn't work for some reason".

Comment: The reason is that if you begin sending output from PHP and *then* try and set headers, you will receive an error as noted in the [2nd paragraph of the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php).